# Performing Analytics over Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

I am working for a small concern and very new to apache cassandra. Studying about cassandra and performing some small analytics like sum function on cassandra DB for creating reports. For the same, Hive and Accunu can be choices.

Datastax Enterprise provides the solution for Apache Cassandra and Hive Integration. Is Datastax Enterprise is the only solution for such integration. Is there any way to resolve the hive and cassandra integration. If so, Can I get the links or documents regarding the same. Is that possible to work the same with the windows platform.

Is any other solution to perform analytics on cassandra DB?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to download DataStax Enterprise (DSE) for Windows but found there is no such option on their website. I suppose they do not support DSE for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cassandra *does* have builtin Hadoop support. You need to set up a standalone Hadoop cluster colocated with Apache Cassandra nodes and then use ColumnFamilyInputFormat and ColumnFamilyOutputFormat to read/write data from/to your Hadoop cluster.